# Compose Text Not Recomposing when change Light and Dark Mode

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've followed [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#0) and try making an app of my own for training. The problem is Light and Dark theme color are not changing accordingly in my training app. I've used the same theme and color as above tutorial and the tutorial app show correct Light and Dark colors. But the training app show like below

[image: Light Mode] [image: Dark Mode]

Some Text() doesn't change color, and it only happens when change Dark and Light mode.

This is my CardScreen

```
@Composable
fun MovieCardScreen(movie: MovieResponse) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        onClick = {
            MovieDetailActivity.start(context = context, movie)
        },
        elevation = 4.dp,
    ) {
        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        ) {
            Row {
                Image(
                    painter = rememberImagePainter(
                        data = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.posterPath}",
                        builder = {
                            crossfade(true)
                            placeholder(R.drawable.ic_bg_movie)
                            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
                        }
                    ),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                )

                Column {
                    Text(
                        text = movie.originalTitle ?: "",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(
                            top = 8.dp,
                            bottom = 8.dp,
                            start = 8.dp,
                            end = 8.dp
                        ),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5.copy(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = movie.overview ?: "",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp),
                        maxLines = 2,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is some Text views are not recomposing sometime. What am I doing wrong here?

my Color.kt

```
val Purple200 = Color(0xFFBB86FC)
val Purple500 = Color(0xFF6200EE)
val Purple700 = Color(0xFF3700B3)
val Teal200 = Color(0xFF03DAC5)

val Navy = Color(0xFF073042)
val Blue = Color(0xFF4285F4)
val LightBlue = Color(0xFFD7EFFE)
val Chartreuse = Color(0xFFEFF7CF)
```

my Theme.kt

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200,
    surface = Blue,
    onSurface = Navy,
    primary = Navy,
    onPrimary = Chartreuse
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = LightBlue,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200,

    // Other default colors to override
    background = Color.White,
    surface = Blue,
    onPrimary = Navy,
    onSecondary = Color.Black,
    onBackground = Color.Black,
    onSurface = Color.White,

)

@Composable
fun MovieDbComposeTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Comment: Which Compose version are you using? Please provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's [mine](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/e408c4f026da2e1a8942dd32a85a75ac) based on your code - it's launched on a clear project with your theme, and works as expected on API 31 emulator. Check if it works for you too.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I am using 1.0.5. I no long have the above issue but it is strange. Like you said, it works if I copy the code into the code lab tutorial project. It just doesn't works in new project. But I gave up on that and tried to implement swipe refresh by wraping accompanist swipe refresh around the LazyColumn and it works now. I don't know why but it is fine now.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/kaungkhantsoe/14bd2fd2f58a36ee351976bf76c7aa93) is old code. [This](https://gist.github.com/kaungkhantsoe/b438a9950acd105c167adcba4b24af30) is working code. Now all Text shows correct color whenever Light and Dark mode changes. I don't know why but it works now.